# Laravel too few arguments to function,0 passed andexactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, controller

I am trying to pass the 2 parameters to my index method in the controller but it does not pass and says 0 have been sent. I have checked if the variables can be shown on the view which it can so that isn't the problem.

In my blade file I have the following <a tag:

```
<a href="{{ route('attack.index', [ $debate->id,$argument->id ])}}" class="card-link">Is the circumstance: <strong>{{$variables->circumstance}}</strong> true?</a>
```

web.php route:
`Route::resource('attack', AttackController::class)->middleware('auth');`

Controller:
`public function index($debate, $argument){//}`

Error message:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AttackController::index(), 0 passed in C:\Users\hakar\argupedia\Argupedia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: You're using `Route::resource` but want to access variables from `index method` in the `Controller` why ?

Comment: `public function index($debate, $argument)` requires 2 route arguments, however the `index` route of a resource controller does not take any arguments. The list of routes created for resource controllers is at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @Al-AminSarker I didn't actually know index method is not meant to take variables, if I changed the controller to not be a resource controller what would I write in the route to access the page and what would I write in the blade to send the variables?

Comment: So, if you don't use `Route::resource`, you need to change `Route` with your  `slugs`. Then you can access these variables.

Comment: @Al-AminSarker I have changed the route to a route with slugs: Route::get('/attack/{debate}{argument}', 'AttackController@schemes');
I also changed the controller to not be a resource controller. Could you please let me know how to write in the href to redirect to this route now and send the two variables $debate->id and $argument->id. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Alano looks my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using one method in a controller, there is no need for a resource route, Better way would be to create a single route like this:

```
Route::get('attack/{debate}/{argument}', 'AttackController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('attack.index');
```

The arguments in the curly brackets are called [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters). Now, in order to pass this parameters, you need to pass them like key => value arrays

```
  <a href="{{route('attack.index',['debate' => $debate->id,'argument' => $argument->id])}}" class="card-link">Is the circumstance: <strong>{{$variables->circumstance}}</strong> true?</a>
```

Now, you have access to these parameters in your controller:

```
public function index($debate, $argument){
   dd($debate, $argument);
}
```

If both parameters are not required here, you can use [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) in your routes, by using ? mark, like this:

```
Route::get('attack/{debate?}/{argument?}', 'AttackController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

You can now pass only one parameter to your route, without crashing your application.

Comment: I tried everything you said, changed the controller from a resource. But still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Did you delete your old resource route? And did you pass those params as `key => val` in your `a` tag?

Comment: Yes i deleted the resource route, and have written it exactly as you have above. URL now looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/attack?debate=1&argument=1 and error is the same.

Comment: Hmm, seems weird to me, this should work. Try clearing your route cache with `php artisan route:clear`. Also, would you mind pasting me the output of the `php artisan route:list`. Also, I edited the `a` tag in my answer to include a route name.

Comment: I tried php artisan route:list and this is happening not sure why. The controller does exist and there is a Use statement for it in the web.php file.  Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [AttackController] does not exist.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear the error started from Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [AttackController] does not exist

Comment: You need to check the namespace for that use statement and the controller itself, maybe you misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

**Blade** File

```
<a href="{{route('search',[$debate->id,$argument->id])}}" class="card-link">Is the circumstance: <strong>{{$variables->circumstance}}</strong> true?</a>
```

**Route** File

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/attack/{debate}/{argument}', 'AttackController@schemes')->name('search');
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function schemes($debate, $argument){
   dd($debate, $argument);
}
```

Comment: Tried your code above and now getting the error: Target class [AttackController] does not exist.
I have the Use statement for the controller in the web file and I am using Laravel 8.

Comment: You have no `AttackController` class in your directory in right way. So, you need to change that.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure I understand, how would I do this?

Comment: Create new controller using this command like 
`php artisan make:controller YourController` and replace `Route` file with this controller. And check how is going...

Comment: My AttackController does exist though I'm not sure why this error is coming up

Comment: Create `UserController` Instead `AttackController` by the laravel create controller comman. And use `UserController` in your `Route` file.

Comment: I tried using a different controller with the create controller command. It simply gives the same error that controller does not exist. I even included the use statement for that controller in the web.php file.

Comment: I included the full namespace for the controller and it is now working! Thank you very much you are a life saver!